# Не могу использовать PUT метод

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

Вопрос про [Eve](https://docs.python-eve.org/)

Я хочу заменить поле в созданном документе. Но у меня проблема с этим делом. Например, у меня есть следующий документ:

```
{
    'answer': {
        'grade': 0
    }
}
```

После этого я хочу получить следующий документ по PATCH-запросу:

```
{
    'answer': {
        'grade': 0,
        'yeah': 1
    }
}
```

Но я хочу убрать поле `grade`. Я знаю, что это делается PUT-запросом. Но в настройках конфигурации EVE я не могу установить метод `PUT` в RESOURSE_ITEMS.

Как я могу решить мою проблему без магии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В EVE это никак не сделать на уровне методов. В EVE есть два способа обновить документ. Либо его полностью перетереть с помощью PATCH, либо добавить новое поле с помощью PUT. По-другому сделать на уровне http-протокола нельзя.

Одним из возможных решений проблемы -- использовать два запроса: 
- достать весь документ с помощью GET и заменить в нём нужное поле 
- полностью обновить документ с помощью PATCH

Можно пойти более сложным путём и воспользоваться [хуками](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#event-hooks). Но данный вариант не предпочтителен, так как он приводит к тому, что часть логики будет реализована в БД и её сложно тестировать. При этом, реализовав одну подобную функцию, Вы рискуете ввести это в практику и сделать из EVE-storage монстра.

**Не стоит недооценивать человеческого фактора**.